# How to set systemd service status to "activ" after the spring boot app has booted?

Tags: java, linux, maven, spring-boot, systemd

I have Spring Boot services setup as systemd services which depand on each other. For that I set f.e. Requiers=config-service. So boot order is correct, the problem is, that the systemd service set its status to "activ" when the corrosponding spring boot app is booting. which mean the next systemd service is starting before the spring boot app is finished. That lead to a failstartup of the spring boot service, which depend on the one before.

I tryn to setup a ExecStartPre=/bin/sleep 30. but the number is bit rondom and the hardware, on which the system is running differnt. so there is a risk, that even this 30s not enough and it feels... unclean

First Spring Boot service is a config service. its systemd service is

```
[Unit]
Description=Config service
After=syslog.target network.target

[Service]
User=pi
ExecStart=/var/mapps/config-service.jar SuccessExitStatus=143

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

its next depending service is

```
[Unit]
Description=Discovery service
After=syslog.target network.target config-service.service
Requires=config-service.service

[Service]
User=pi
ExecStart=/var/myapps/discovery-service.jar SuccessExitStatus=143

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

To make the Spring Boot Apps bootable as systemd service i added

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
      <executable>true</executable>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

in my pom.xml

I expected, that the systemd service go into status "active" after the Spring Boot Service is up, but the systemd service is "acive" when the Spring Boot Service starts booting.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions about the Linux operating system and its utilities should be asked, instead, on https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Rob I dont know if it is a pure linux problem. Maybe the soltuion is in Java in the configuration to make the spring boot app set status, when its up. At the end, the linux services, does, what it supposed to do. The jar, in my point of view, simple says to early "im up"